# Laravel Eloquent - Where In All

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In **Laravel 4.2**, I am trying to achieve a query that returns all users, that have all of certain activities. As of now, I have a query that returns all users that have one of many activities:

```
//$selectedActivities being an array
        $userByActivities = User::with('activities')
                ->whereHas('activities', function($query) use($selectedActivities){
                    $query->whereIn('id', $selectedActivities);
                })->get();
```

To be more clear: given activities *a,b,c*. I am looking for all users that have activity *a AND b AND c*. My query returns all users that have activity *a OR b OR c*.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

The solution offered by [lukasgeiter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903366/lukasgeiter) results in following query:

```
select * from `users` where 
        (select count(*) from `activities` inner join `activity_user` on `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id` where `activity_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = '7') >= 1 
        and (select count(*) from `activities` inner join `activity_user` on `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id` where `activity_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = '3') >= 1 
        and (select count(*) from `activities` inner join `activity_user` on `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id` where `activity_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = '1') >= 1 
        and (select count(*) from `activities` inner join `activity_user` on `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id` where `activity_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` = '2') >= 1
```

Whereas the solution offered by [Jarek Tkaczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/784588/jarek-tkaczyk):

```
$userByActivities = User::with('activities')
 ->whereHas('activities', function($query) use($selectedActivities) {
     $query->selectRaw('count(distinct id)')->whereIn('id', $selectedActivities);
 }, '=', count($selectedActivities))->get();
```

for a similar request, results in following query:

```
select * from `users` where (select count(distinct id) from `activities` 
    inner join `activity_user` on `activities`.`id` = `activity_user`.`activity_id` 
    where `activity_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `id` in ('7', '3', '1', '2')) = 4
```

Comment: The solution proposed by Jarek Tkaczyk is far more optimized than the accepted one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You'll have to add multiple `whereHas` for that:

```
$query = User::with('activities');
foreach($selectedActivities as $activityId){
    $query->whereHas('activities', function($q) use ($activityId){
        $q->where('id', $activityId);
    });
}
$userByActivities = $query->get();
```

Comment: It's overkill for unknown number of related items. You should adjust the count to `count(distinct id)` and make `whereHas` look for exact number of items in the array.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk how to do that?

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting `Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)` the problem is the nested `selectCount` adds to the normal `select count(*)` instead of overriding the existing select, so changing to `$query->distinct()->whereIn('id', $selectedActivities);` did the trick for me, or changing to `$query->select(DB::raw(count(distinct id)))`

Comment: `$query->distinct()->whereIn('id', $selectedActivities);` worked for me, thanks