# select all products that have all of selected options via a pivot table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a `Product` and `Option` model that have a **many to many** relationship via a `Product_Option`. Product_Option have option_id and product_id fields.

Now I have an array of option_ids and I want to select All Products that have all of those Options (There may be other options, but I want to select only products that have all of these options  at the same time.)

I wrote this code but it return all products that have at least one of those options:

```
$products = Product::with(['translations'])->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($options) {
                    $query->whereIn('options.id', $options);
                })->toSql();
```

Please help me to find best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28633509/10573560)

you could do it using multiple 'whereHas':

```
$products = Product::with(['translations']);
        foreach ($options as $option)
        {
            $products=$products->whereHas('options', function ($query) use ($option) {
                $query->where('options.id', $option);
            });
        }
        $products=$products->toSql();
```