# Laravel whereIn not giving desired result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I have the following two tables:

```
unotes    unote_unit
======    ==========
id        unote_id
notes     unit_id
```

I am trying to retrieve `unotes` row whose related `unit_id` columns exactly match an input array.

So, I run following query:

```php
$unote = UNote::whereHas('units', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereIn('units.id', $request->unit_lists);
    })
    ->withCount('units')
    ->having('units_count', '=', $u_list_count)
    ->get()
    ->pluck("id");
```

But, the problem with the above query is that even if it has just a single matching `unit_id`, it retrieves the data. For example I have following datasets:

```
unotes //with related unit_id
========
id = 3 //49865, 49866, 49867
id = 4  //49865, 49866
```

With above mentioned code, if I pass `[49866,55555]`, it should return nothing but it returns ids 3 and 4, which contain one match but not all.

I have found similar question on [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/eloquent-wherein-all?page=1) as well but running the query returns `Cardinality violation: 1241 Operand should contain 2 column(s)`:

```
$unote = UNote::with('units')
    ->whereHas('units', function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->selectRaw("count(distinct id)")->whereIn('id', $request->unit_lists);
    }, '=', $u_list_count)
    ->get()
    ->pluck("id");
```

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633389/laravel-eloquent-where-in-all), but seems it is too expensive.

Here is the dummy SQL to get started: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3d1f7/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `whereHas` just adds a `WHERE EXISTS` clause to the query with your specified filters, a `whereIn` will indeed return true for any matches. One thing you could try is running a raw subquery to get a list of device IDs and compare it.

```php
$search_ids = [49866, 49865];
sort($search_ids);
$search_ids = implode(",", $search_ids);

Unote::select("id")
    ->whereRaw(
        "(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(unit_id ORDER BY unit_id) FROM unote_unit WHERE unote_id = unotes.id) = ?",
        [$search_ids]
    )
    ->get()
    ->pluck("id");
```

Note, if you have soft deletes enabled you will also want to filter out soft deleted items in the subquery.

Comment: Does not seems working yet, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3d1f7/49 showing two rows on passing, `[49865, 49866]`. Actually, it should have returned only id `4`

Comment: Right I forgot you wanted exact match. So, replace `RLIKE` with `=`, and change parameter to just `$search_ids`.