# Laravel Eloquent match to all parameters of join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have a table that houses hotel ids and amenity ids. When a user chooses amenities i need to only pull hotels that have ALL of the chosen amenities. As of now it gets me all hotels that have at least one. How can i change this builder query to handle it so it does not include hotels that do not have all of them.

```
$builder = Hotels::query(); 
$builder->select('hotels.id','hotels'.'hotels_name')
$request_amenities = $request->amenities;
$builder->join('amenities_hotels', function ($join) use($request_amenities) {
    $join->on('amenities_hotels.hotel_id', '=', 'hotel.id')
            ->whereIn('amenities_hotels.amenities_id', $request_amenities);
});
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing what `$builder` is. But you can take a look at `whereHas`

Comment: builder is the query builder. Starts like $builder = Hotels::query(); $builder->select('hotels.id','hotels'.'hotels_name')

Comment: does this give you the desired result? `$hotels = Hotel::select(['id','hotels_name'])->whereHas('amenities', function($query) use($request){return $query->whereIn('id', $request->amenities);})->get()`? Adding this as a comment as I don't know the relevant names of relations, tables or columns.

Comment: i get Call to undefined method App\Hotels::AmenitiesHotel() which leaves me to believe I would need to set up a relationship within that Model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something like `WhereAll` you need ...

you have to add `whereHas`, for every Item in your array.

```
 $builder = Hotels::query();
        $builder->select('hotels.id', 'hotels' . 'hotels_name');
        $request_amenities = $request->amenities;
        if($request_amenities!=null)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $this->count($request_amenities); $i++) {
                $builder = $builder->whereHas('amenitiesHotels', function ($query) use ($i, $request_amenities) {
                    $query->where('amenities_hotels.amenities_id', $request_amenities[$i]);
                });
        }
```

see more about where in all in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28633389/10573560)

Comment: I went with a variation of this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Hotels model.

```php
// ...

    public function amenities(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            Amenities::class,
            "amenities_hotels"
        );
    }

//  ...
```

Query to run.

```php
Hotels::select(['hotels.id','hotels'.'hotels_name'])

->whereHas('amenities', function ($query, $request_amenities) {

    $query->whereIn('amenities.id', $request_amenities);

}, '=', count($request_amenities))->get();
```

The above query tells Laravel to load the hotels that have `count($request_amenities)` ***amenities*** relation records when the ***amenities*** relation records are filtered by the given array of IDs.

Resource: ["Where Has All" Functionality in Laravel](https://owenconti.com/posts/wherehasall-functionality-in-laravel)

Comment: Im going to look into this more, I needed to get this out and the other answer was a quicker path to it but I like the approach on this. Thanks for the help.